# Test play controller with session data

Tags: junit, playframework, mockito

I have a simple controller test.

```
route(fakeRequest(routes.Accounts.accounts()).session("sessionref","fakeSession"));
```

Secured Autheticator looks like this:

```
public class Secured extends play.mvc.Security.Authenticator {

@Inject
AuthServices authService;

public String getUsername(Http.Context context) {
    return authService.checkSession(context);
}

@Override
public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context context) {
    return ok(index.render(formFactory.form(forms.LoginForm.class)));
}
```

}

How can i mock `authService`?
I tried to mock with guice bind but this method don't work

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    startPlay();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(AuthServices.class)
                    .toInstance(authServices);
        }
    };

    GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
            .builder(new play.ApplicationLoader.Context(Environment.simple()))
            .in(Mode.TEST)
            .overrides(testModule);
    Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [this](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/06/unit-testing-powermock-mocking-play.html) for testing Play controllers and follow [this example](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/08/overriding-guice-dependency-injection-playframework.html) for testing with Guice.

For your case it is something like this:

```
public class MyTest extends WithApplication {
    @Mock
    AuthServices mockAuthService;

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
            .overrides(bind(CacheProvider.class).toInstance(mockAuthService))
            .in(Mode.TEST)
            .build();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccounts() {
        running(provideApplication(), () -> {                
            RequestBuilder testRequest = Helpers.fakeRequest(controllers.routes.Accounts.accounts()).session("sessionref","fakeSession");
                Result result = route(testRequest);
                //assert here the expected result
        });
    }
}
```